# Troubleshooting Electric Water Heather

Tags: water-heater, circuit-breaker

My water heater stopped working in the past few days.  All water comes out cold.  The water heater makes no noise and is also cold to the touch.

I have tried cutting power to the water heater (see switch on outside of fusebox pic #6).  I have tried hitting the reset button on the water heater (see pic #3).  Neither of these actions resulted in any discernible effect (no noise, no hot water, etc...).

I suspect the issue may be w/ the fusebox which sends power to the water heater.

Under the assumption that the heater itself is not to blame, how do I troubleshoot this?  Can I do it w/ parts I pick up at home depot?

[image: Water Heater, sticker #1]

[image: Water Heater, sticker #2]

[image: Water Heater, front panel]

[image: Inside of Door, Fusebox to which heater is connected?]

[image: Interior, Fusebox to which heater is connected?]

[image: Front + Switch, Fusebox to which heater is connected?]

Comment: Do you have a voltmeter?

Comment: Yes, just got one...

Comment: Is there 240V at the water heater? Be safe while making this measurement

Comment: Water Heater not getting anything.  Replaced fuses, still nothing.

Comment: Trace the circuit upstream from the fuses then

Comment: The power to the fusebox seems to come directly from outside.  Unsure of where to place leads to safely test fusebox (depicted above in second-to-last image).

Comment: It looks like the two terminals at the bottom of the box with the black wires going into them are where you'd test the line voltage going in.

Comment: Voltimeter set to VAC 600, reading was in the low tens.  The I can't trace the power for this fusebox to any other fuse/breaker box.  It seems to come in directly from the outside...

Comment: Weird.  Perhaps the line from the outside is broken?  Also, do you have a breaker box on the outside of your house?

Comment: No breaker box on the outside, though there do appear to be two different meters.  The fusebox that the water heater is drawing from may not be the same one as the main breaker from which the rest of the house draws.  Everything else in the house works...

Comment: Do both meters indicate power consumption?

Comment: Is your meter digital or analog if analogue make sure you are reading the voltage on the correct scale.  Also measure from each fuse to ground, it looks like the box is grounded you may have 120 on 1 side and nothing on the other. This would point to a failed wire possibly at the meter. In some states you might have to call the power company to pull the meter if it doesn't have an access panel to check the wiring if you find one of the legs to the fuse box doesn't have 120v to ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the problem was the meter.  The water heater's breaker box wasn't getting any power from the meter, and so the water heater had no power.  This explains why I never read any real amount of voltage anywhere.  Electric company sent someone over to resolve it.